# Is Python good enough for big applications?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

From the moment I have faced Python, the only thing I can say for it is "It is awesome". I am using Django framework and I am amazed by how quick things happen and how developer friendly this language is. But from many sides I hear that Python is a scripting language, and very useful for small things, experiments etc.

So the question is can a big and heavy loaded application be built in Python (and django)? As I mainly focus on web development, examples of such applications could be Stack Overflow, Facebook, Amazon etc.

---

P.S. According to many of the answers maybe I have to rephrase the question. There are several big applications working with Python (the best example is You Tube) so it can handle them but why then it is not so popular for large projects as (for example) Java, C++ and .NET?

Comment: Why do you care anyway? If your site will become so popular, you probably rewrite it anyway.

Comment: You’re questioning Python’s capacity because you heard it’s useful for small, fast experiments? That doesn’t mean it’s useless for big things.

Comment: jleedev, it doesn't mean it's good for big things either.

Comment: The problems you face becoming a Stack Overflow, Facebook or Amazon aren't going to be because of your language, they're going to be because your architecture.  You really can't anticipate that sort of popularity, so don't bother trying to engineer it in.  Get users & fix things down the road rather than worrying about being Facebook-scale on launch day.  Don't waste time optimizing things that don't need it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Python is a pleasure to work with on big applications. Compared to other enterprise-popular languages you get:

- No compilation time, if you ever worked on a large C++ project you know how time consuming this can get
- A concise and clean syntax that makes reading code easier, also a big time saver when reading someone else's code or even yours when it was written long time ago
- Portability at the core level, if it's important for your app to run on more than one platform it certainly helps
- It's fast enough for most things, and when it's not, rewriting hot spots in C is trivial with tools such as Cython and numpy. People advocating against dynamic languages for speed reasons have forgotten the 80-20 rule (or never heard about it). The important thing to consider when choosing a language for a performance-critical application IMHO is how easily you can gain access to the C level when needed, and Python is great for that

It's not a magic language however, you need to use the same techniques used for big projects in other languages: TDD (some may argue that it's more important than in other languages because of the lack of type checking, but that's not a win for other languages, unit tests are **always** important in big projects), clean OO design, etc... or maintaining your application will become a nightmare.

The main reason for its lack of acceptance in enterprise compared to .NET, Java et al. is probably not having herds of consultants and "certified specialists" bragging about their tool being the best thing on Earth. I also heard Java was easily accepted because its syntax resembled C++... that may not be such a silly idea considering C# also chose to take this route.

Comment: All of these are very fine points. I could only add that python automatically compiles modules to bytecode and tools like memcache or fastcgi can also improve performance.

Comment: Also 90% of the run time is in 10% of the code so find the hot spots (the inner loops) and try simple things like @numba.jit, numpy matrix operations, or transpiling into Julia.  If you need more speed you can transpile to Rust.

Answer (score 14):

Google tend to use python for a lot, so I assume its ready for big time. We use python as glue for our products so we're happy with it.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know You Tube works on python, but recently I watch a Google Python Class movie(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk&feature=channel) where it was stated again that Python is very useful for small things and experiments.

Comment: It is useful for small things and experiments because you will write things much faster in python then in most other languages, and when you experimenting you don't want to waste too much time you could spend on actual development. People tend to develop and test in python then write it down in C/C++ for example and bind it into python if they need speed.

Comment: I would counter that by saying - that if a language/technology stack works in the small but doesn't scale then yes you'd do this. However I would suggest that python does scale in the main. However it may not for your use case, in which case another stack may be a better 'implementation in the large' option.

Answer (score 9):

The back end of YouTube is almost entirely in Python.  [Here](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-6304964351441328559#) is a talk by Cuong Do Cuong, the engineering manager on the YouTube scalability team that goes into a lot of detail of the issues they faced and how they solved them.  He points out that lanaguage speed is almost never a bottleneck.

I suspect that YouTube has a significantly higher load that whatever you are working on will.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question really boils down to what you have in mind when you say "big application". The simple answer will be "yes". Python serves as the backbone for incredibly complex systems and it does so elegantly (just take a look at how large yet well designed Twisted & Django are). However, it's a tool like any other. It contains performance tradeoffs that may or may not be well suited to your application domain.

If you're looking to build a high-performance flight simulator that must run complex calculations at over 1000Hz... then Python probably isn't the right choice for the whole project. If, on the other hand, single-CPU performance isn't a predominant factor or the application will be spread out over multiple servers to achieve scalability requirements, Python will likely be a good choice.

It's amazing how easily people forget just how expensive development time is. Python is well known for the incredible speed with which production quality applications can be developed. For almost anything non trivial, the development time saved will *far* outweigh the cost associated with tossing a few extra servers into the pool.

Comment: on several forums I read django is not so well designed. Not a Python fault anyway.

Comment: The "1000 Hz flight simulator" is probably not a good example, the vast majority of games are driven by scripting languages these days (more often LUA than Python, but that's because it offers more advanced embedding features), with only time-critical parts written in low level languages.

Comment: That's definitely true of games, however they don't run at 1000Hz. Most high-fidelity flight simulators (those used in the Test & Evaluation arena) typically have enough performance critical code to rule out Python as the predominant language. Anyway the point is that, while uncommon, sometimes you really do need the speed offered by compiled languages.

Comment: Yes, it matters for time-critical parts. I don't see what a 1000 Hz simulator has that is so different than one running at 60, 80% of the execution time goes in 20% of the code.

Comment: Remember that the 80/20 generalization is just that, a generalization. Engine models interacting with Airwake models interacting with weather models consume a tremendous amount of computing power. Also, a 1000Hz simulation is very susceptible to timing fluctations. Any memory allocation or other system calls can ruin the calculations due to os-imposed delays. On the surface gaming and T&E environments seem similar but, in reality, they're totally different worlds. The same holds for many other application domains. Generalizations are useful but remember to respect their limitations.

Comment: 9 years too late but you can prototype your app in Python then transpile it to Julia when you need speed.

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes you can.

> I am mainly focused on the web development so for examples I can give Stack Overflow, Facebook, Amazon etc.

[Reddit.com](http://reddit.com) is written in Python. It has a large user base and receives a fair amount of traffic and seems to be doing well. Reddit doesn't use Django though.

Answer (score 4):

Python is ideal for web development. It's light, easy, and excels at gluing other bits together, and working with high level interfaces. If and when I do "web" development, I wouldn't use anything else.

### Update0

It's also a superior language for scripting, small cross platform applications and prototyping. It only really starts to crumble when extreme performance requirements are *stringent*. That is, it's holding things up in a big way. I also find it's difficult to refactor (a property of dynamic typing), and to utilize platform specific bindings. These things can be worked around (quite easily, due to Python's C implementation, and numerous modules for this purpose), just as in most other good languages.

Python is the best high level language, the only language it can't replace is C.

Comment: I think the code re-factoring argument is very important, and I wonder why no one else mentions this. It is also important to mention that an IDE like visual studio is extremely powerful for creating and maintaining big applications.
We often discuss this at my work place where we only use java and .Net. However, when I come home I fire up PyCharm and starts coding python.
I believe that with the optional typing introduced in python3 and with an IDE like PyCharm, -python is slowly converging towards the awesomeness of .Net and visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

See by yourself :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software

I think it can handle big apps.

Answer (score 3):

There two very important factors with python:

1) Easy to use

2) Easy to interface with other programming languages

### FACTOR 1

Because python a language that emphasizes , simplicity , readability of code both for its own syntax and libraries, that equal to writing less code. And for software that is big this is very important. Your is simple, easier to understand by someone else, easier to debug , easier to recode , rewrite and modify. Easy to exchange between a team of many people.

### FACTOR 2

Why reinvent that wheel ? You want to use a C/C++ library ? How about a Java or .NET library ? Python will let you do exactly that and will even spoil you with allowing you to enjoy the experience without ever leaving python's syntax comfort zone. Jython, Ironpython, Cython, ctypes ,pyrex etc are excellent tools making python limitless with its capabilities let you code in all those diffirent languages/frameworks/runtimes always with python syntax. What more could you ask for ?

In the end its python flexibility that makes it accelerate in the gain of its popularity, always hand in hand with the ease of use . Power and ease of use is a huge temptation  too hard to resist for small,big or huge developers alike.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer your revised question about why would anyone use a different language or technology stack.  First, I love Python.  Great language and definitely has its merits.  However, I choose C#/.NET as my technology of choice and use Python for scripting.

Yes, Python as a language is very simple/clean and there isn't compile time.  However, I find it many times easier to work with a strongly/statically typed language.  #1 reason is IntelliSense (and I mean GOOD IntelliSense - haven't been satisfied with Python editors in this regard).  IntelliSense makes a huge difference in ease/speed of development.

C# is backed by Microsoft (for better or worse).  While the h8t3rs out there can throw rocks, it is hard to deny that Microsoft has technology for the entire stack (desktop, server, web, mobile, etc.) and it all integrates very nicely.  I also know that it is supported by hundreds of developers who are dedicated to providing the best experience possible.  I also can go to a plethora of sites and watch videos, read articles, and find what I need for just about anything.  Support is nice.

I know Python has an excellent (and large) range of libraries and frameworks at its disposal, but I have also felt a certain lack of continuity between the various projects.  Use this 3rd-party library here, throw this 3rd party library in there, use this open source project here...And while I love open source, it takes a much longer time to reach the quality in which Microsoft has put out.

Lastly, Visual Studio is one of the most excellent IDE's I've ever experienced.  I know there are many fine text editors out there (I love you VIM!), but it is hard to beat the integration of source control, code editing, compiling, building, publishing, testing, and deploying all wrapped into a most excellent package.

All this to say, Python is great and can perform wonderfully on large sites - don't get me confused.  However, there are valid arguments for using enterprise technologies.  It just depends on what resources you (or your team) will need, what you are already familiar with, and how you plan to scale when your application is successful.  If you are comfortable with the technology and libraries, have a community to answer tough questions, and can compartmentalize your code so that if you ever do need to re-write it, it is already broken up, then I say you will do just fine.

Comment: Check out PyCharm, its almost as good as VS.

Comment: IntelliSense often breaks in VS (see the number of threads on this topic by just googling it). C# isn't (yet) multiplatform. You have Mono, but there are many people who think that if at some point Mono becomes popular enough Microsoft will simple troll it with patent claims, which will bring it to sever alternation or (more likely) complete annihilation. If you have to work on a non-Windows platform C# is a no go. For Python there are many decent editors - PyCharm, Spyder etc. You also have the ever so great `ipython` that allows you write code and run it while inside your browser.

Comment: For many tasks REPL based development gives you more information than IntelliSense (it lets you interact with your running application and see values, change classes, and methods, you can also do deepreload from within IPython), just set a break point within a function you want to edit or code then go to the REPL and code inside the REPL, then copy/paste your finished code into your editor.  You can also press  ALT+Shift+E to evaluate a line in the REPL. Make sure to use IPython as the default shell is horrible, and has problems with multiline statements.

Comment: Just tried attaching Python debugger to the REPL and its broken : ( for Python 3.7.  However, using Hy with parinfer is an awesome way to do metaprogramming in Python https://shaunlebron.github.io/parinfer/.http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#macros

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise - Yes, certainly for web frontends. The performance bottleneck is *always* the database.

Comment: not always. I would say that the bottle neck in mainstream large systems generally is inter machine communications. Sometimes this is DB, sometimes just plain an simple people writing code assuming that the functions will return within microseconds but not taking into account that the call is an rpc and could takes seconds.

Comment: @Preet, sure it's possible to write a crappy implementation in any language.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Python give you all of the best power of programming. Easy, powerful and quick!
Enjoy it in big your projoect!

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906795/what-are-some-famous-websites-built-in-django for examples of how Python (in this case Django) can handle heavy load.

Disqus, Pinterest, Pownce and Instagram all handle hundreds of requests per second, millions of users etc.